# Кэш карт Яндекс.карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть Яндекс.карты версии 3.84 + Android 6. Проблема с сохранением карт на внешней SD-карте.

Настройки -> Дополнительные настройки -> Папка с картами

На Андроид 4.2.2 выводится окно ввода пути.

На Андроид 5 выводится два варианта выбора: 1) внутренняя память 2) Внешная SD-карта. При выборе внешней карты переключение происходит.

На Андроид 6.0.1 выводится два варианта выбора: 1) внутренняя память 2) Внешная SD-карта. При выборе внешней карты выдаётся ошибка "Неправильный путь".
К слову, карта памяти монтируется телефоном Samsung как /mnt/XXXX-XXXX, где Х - число или буква.

Пытался разобраться в исходниках, дабы явно прописать путь, но безрезультатно.

Андроид 6.0.1 + Яндекс.карты версии 4 - переключение происходит корректно.

Comment: Это вопрос про приложение Яндекс.Карты, про JS API Карт или про MapKit?

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не знаю, не специалист. Но полагаю, явное прописывание пути на карту sd решило бы проблему.